# How to use RxJava.Observable instead of AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

Using AsyncTask to run some tasks I get crashes so I am trying to move to RxJava.

I can get the following code to run which prints `Hello World!` but how can I execute a **function** instead of just `Hello World!`???? Placing a function gives Syntax error.

```
Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super String> sub) {
                    sub.onNext("Hello, world!");
                    sub.onCompleted();
                }
            }
    );


    Subscriber<String> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            mLogger.printToLog(className + " -> " + MethodName.methodName() + ": s =" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }
    };

    //Should Output Hello, World! AND IT DOES!
    myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);
```

Comment: If your method returns a String it should work just fine. Could you post the code that *doesn't* work rather than the code that does work? :) Also I remember using this french tutorial to play with RxJava in the past http://blog.xebia.fr/2014/01/10/android-oubliez-definitivement-les-asynctask-avec-rxjava/ , you can see the code parts for inspiration if you don't understand french.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippeA that worked. I wanted to run a function that was returning a `void` but now I am returning a Dummy String and that's working.

Comment: @user1406716: That sounds like you are using doing some side-effecty stuff in your `OnSubscribe.call()` - in that case I would encourage you to try to think about the problem in a more functional way. In that sense a funtion is not something you can "run" but something that takes input and generates output *from that input*. IMO, RxJava works best if your Observables represent pure (i. e. side-effect free) flows of data and if you do the side-effecty stuff in your `Subscriber`.

Comment: I made an answer from my comment so you can accept it and resolve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your method return a String and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for doOnNext():

```
myObservable.doOnNext(runSomething()).subscribe();
```